# Apocalyptic movie with either mutated monkeys or gargoyles in New York City

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

Trying to remember a movie I watched as a kid probably around 2005-2007 which had a scene of flying gargoyles or mutated monkeys trying to get the survivors inside a building in apocalyptic New York City. I can't remember 100% or not if it also involved time travel or not, I feel like it did with time "ripples" spreading out and destroying the beasts.

Comment: There's [12 Monkey](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114746/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), which isn't exactly what you're describing, but sort of fits if you squint at it just right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like the movie version of [A Sound of Thunder](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0318081/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) - the time (2005) is the right period. Mutated monkeys, time travel, and an apocalyptic city. Also, time 'rippled' changing everything and/or was going to potentially destroy the present.

Here's [the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xaKvSonbG8).

Comment: That's it, I kept looking for it with the word butterfly in it bringing me to the butterfly effect.

Comment: I can understand why - in the short story (maybe the movie) a guy falls off the path while trying to shoot a dinosaur and crushes a butterfly. It changes the future.